# What is NuGet.CommandLine packagerererence good for?

Tags: asp.net-core, nuget, csproj

In *.csproj of my aspnetcore app I see:

```
 <PackageReference Include="NuGet.CommandLine" Version="4.1.0" />
```

What it is good for?

If my environment hadn't NuGet CLI I wouldn't be able to restore this package. When I have it I don't need the package, do I?

Answer (score 1):

> What it is good for?

TLDR, it is good for bringing NuGet capabilies to Linux and Mac.

According to [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/guides/install-nuget):

> The NuGet CLI is the command-line utility for Windows that provides
>   all NuGet capabilities; it can also be run on Mac OSX and Linux using
>   Mono, or through the .NET Core CLI (dotnet).

So it is just cross-platform command-line version of `NuGet Package Manager` in Visual Studio, which is Windows only. So if you using Visual Studio in Window you basically don't need it, you can just use built-in `NuGet Package Manager`. But if you want use NuGet capabilities in Linux or Mac, or you have just Visual Studio Code in Windows (without Visual Studio 2017) you definitely need this package.